# Java - events within events?

Tags: java

I have a textfield and a button.

They have identical actionPerformed event listener. (e.g. when user clicks a button and when user hits ENTER).

Is there a way to avoid this kind of duplication of code? It just becomes a pain in the __ modifying the code in 2 places for each such case.

I was thinking would it be possible to call a button event inside of a textfield event, analogous like calling a function inside of another function?

**EDIT:**

Passing the same addActionPerformed method call to both textfield and button did the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are complaining because you are using an anonymous inner class for both. So don't do that. Create a first-class class, and create an instance that you pass to both component's addActionListener.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much it. Not quite sure whether there's another problem here. Maybe posting code would allow us to see if there's some issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
    ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //...
        }
    };
    Button button = new Button();
    button.addActionListener(actionListener );
    TextField  textField = new TextField();
    textField.addActionListener(actionListener);
```

or not so elegant but possible call a third method `doIt()` in your both `actionPerformed()` methods